# mismatch token laravel on add form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this form to create a new article. User inputs everything correctly but i get a return of `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:`. I saw another post saying that because i used the open form Tag it will already add this for me and to take it out. How do i take this out? or is there some other problem that im overlooking?

here is my controller

```
public function store( AddArticleController $request)
{
    $request= $request->all();
    $request['user_id']=Auth::id();
    Article::create($request->all());


    return redirect('/user');
}
```

and here is the html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/article/add') }}">
                {!! Form::open(
                array(
                'class' => 'form',
                'novalidate' => 'novalidate',
                'files' => true)) !!}
                <div class = "form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('title','Title:', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    {!! Form::text('title',null, ['class' => 'form-control']),  !!}

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('title','Image:', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::file('image') !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('title','Type:', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                    {!! Form::select('type', array('select' => 'select','fashion' => 'Fashion', 'music' => 'Music', 'dance' => 'Dance', 'event' => 'Event'))!!}
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class = "form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('body','Comment:', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::textarea('body',null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('body',' ', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                    {!! Form:: submit('Sumbit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, which version of Laravel do you use?

The Laravel's HTML Helper has been removed in the version 5 of Laravel and is now not updated. If you still want to use this helper I recommend you to use the version updated by the community https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html.

For your problem, if you don't use the helper, you need to add the token manualy by adding `{!! csrf_token() !!}` in your form. You can find more information in the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: Now when i add the token, it tells me that method all doesn't exist? Before everything worked fine if i left out the user_id portion..What does this mean?

Comment: Which `all()` method? From your request?

Comment: Im using the most recent 5 i believe.  $request= $request->all();
        $request['user_id']=Auth::id();
        Article::create($request->all());

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of either the `<form>` tag or from `{{ Form::open() }}` from your code.

---

The Laravel's form generator (which is depricated since Laravel 5) allows you to write that syntax `{{ Form::open() }}` which is rendered to plain html tag `<form>`.

so in your case the right way to go would be either

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/article/add') }}">
{!! csrf_token() !!}     // note that in this case we need to put csrf token manuall

......
</form>
```

OR

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => url('/article/add'), 'novalidate' => 'novalidate' 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form form-horizontal']) !!}
... //your fields and you don't have to explicitly include csrf token. Form::open() will do that for you
{!! Form::close() !!}
```